# cakephp: notice 8:undefined index: id error

Tags: cakephp, notice, undefined-index

i'm getting Undefined index: id [APP\controllers\merry_parents_controller.php, line 31]Code

```
debug($this->data['MerryParent']);
    echo 'id: '.$this->data['MerryParent']['id'];

 MerryParentsController::login() - APP\controllers\merry_parents_controller.php, line 31
 Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE\cake\dispatcher.php, line 204
 Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE\cake\dispatcher.php, line 171
 [main] - APP\webroot\index.php, line 83
```

My code:

merry_parents_controller.php

```
if ($this->Auth->user()){
            //debug($this->Auth->user());
            $this->data['MerryParent']=$this->Auth->user();
            debug($this->data['MerryParent']);
            echo 'id: '.$this->data['MerryParent']['id'];
```

for debug($this->data['MerryParent']), the record is displaying fine:

```
Array
 (
  [MerryParent] => Array
    (
    [id] => 2
    [initial] => Ms
    [username] => hong
    [email] => hong7@yahoo.com
    [password2] => hong7
    [landline] => 
    [mobile] => 293472389472
    [address] => dsaflkjasdlfk
    [state_id] => 5
    [city_id] => 62
    [postal_code] => 825729
    [created] => 2011-08-02 10:29:59
    [modified] => 2011-09-26 06:42:27
     )
)
```

but when i try 
echo 'id: '.$this->data['MerryParent']['id'];

i'm getting notice 8: undefined index error. I have no idea on what is the problem. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [MerryParent] => Array
    (
        [MerryParent] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            ...
```

The id you're looking for is in `$this->data['MerryParent']['MerryParent']['id']`. You probably want

```
$this->data = $this->Auth->user();
```